# DateTime returning null when parsed

Tags: d3.js

I'm attempting to plot the date/time on the x axis of my line graph but with no success.

I've tried every variation of the time.format from the D3 docs but date/time still returning null:

```
    dateTimeTaken: null
    reading: "14.5"
```

The x axis and y axis are being displayed but not the actual graph.

https://gist.github.com/5fc4cd5f41a6ddf2df23

I know its a problem with the way I'm parsing the date but nothing I'm doing seems to work - can anyone help?

**UPDATE:**  This format works  - d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse, but now have an additional line showing on graph as shown in image below.

[image]

Comment: Could it be that `var format` is not a function? so it's not taking the argument you're expecting to pass into it?

Comment: Looked at few examples that this has worked perfectly for e.g http://bl.ocks.org/3883245 I just presumed it must be something I'm doing with the parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the select statement in my PHP code to group by dateTimeTaken - wasn't an additional line - data just wasn't in any sequential order.